# SQL how to find continuous count of rows that exceed a value over time

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

```
ID value timestamp1 timestamp2
1    1.     1.          1
1.   2.     2           1
1.   0.     3           1
1.   2.     4.          1
2.   2.     3           4
2.   2.     4.          4
```

I need to figure out how to query this table such that I find out the continuous count for each ID in which the value is equal or above 1 and the timestamp1 is bigger than timestamp 2. So for example:

ID 1 will have a count of 2 because the 3rd row is 0 and even though the 4th is of value 2 I need for it to be continuous.

ID 2 will have a count of 1 because row 4 timestamp 1 is below timstamp 2.

Please help, have tried a bunch of things

Comment: The time stampfilter is trivial. It should likely be removed form the question and the data collapsed (and then expanded), such that the more interesting ‘find continuous count’ is exposed with better data. Trivially, a query can return a derived table with “... WHERE t1 > t2”.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots they are two very different database products

Comment: @user2864740 . . . Your explanation and your data do not agree.  `timestamp1` is not bigger than `timestamp2` in the first row.

Comment: It’s not my data.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can get each range as:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp1) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, (value >= 1), (timestamp1 >= timestamp2)
                                order by timestamp1
                               ) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
where value >= 1 and (timestamp1 >= timestamp2)
group by id, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

In Postgres, you can get the maximum using `distinct on`.  I'm guessing that you are using Redshift and under the mistaken impression that it is equivalent to Postgres (it might have been decades ago).  You can get what you want using an additional level of aggregation:

```
select id, max(cnt)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp1) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by id, (value >= 1), (timestamp1 >= timestamp2)
                                      order by timestamp1
                                     ) as seqnum_2
            from t
           ) t
      where value >= 1 and (timestamp1 >= timestamp2)
      group by id, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
     ) ig
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec0171acb3004abe01dc224b84520446) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is very close but it will provide the count for multiple continuous runs...for example:

```
ID value timestamp1 timestamp2
1    1.     1.          1
1.   2.     2           1
1.   0.     3           1
1.   2.     4.          1
1.   2.     5           4
1.   2.     6.          4```

Will return 2 and 3 and I only want the 2 value. I tried do include timestamp and get the closest one to the value which is a bit hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: @user3210458 . . . Your logic only makes sense if you mean continuous rows where `timestamp1` is equal to or bigger than `timestamp2` and `value = 0`.  The queries in this answer produce the correct results, with that modification.  This answers your question.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59303af9aa30a214009b7378220f41b8

I added a couple more fields 

The result here is 3 for 1 but I need the length of the FIRST duration so it should be 2.

I am not looking for the max length after the fact but the duration that it is above the criteria. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=072eeed2d6978c8da2ebe711362335d6

better example - here the max is 3 but I am looking for the first duration which will be 2